# Float numbers is Javascript are being rounded

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am experiencing some strange behaviour with float numbers in a javascript array.

When I loop over the array like this:

```
$.each(values, function(key,data) {
 console.log(key +": "+data);
})
```

I see the numbers correctly as follows:

```
4: 39.9283296
spline:167 5: -3.4983312
spline:167 6: 823.487609863281
```

But when I try to access the data directly using the array index like this:

```
console.log(data[4] + " " +data[5] + " " +data[6])
```

The numbers get rounded:

```
2 8 3
```

I would really apprecaite it if someone could explain what is going on here, and how I can access the original data. TIA!

Comment: Check the first value: `39.9283296`. Now think of it as a string - data[4] = 2, data[5] = 8, data[6] = 3.

Comment: Can you add the data array as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're trying to access a string like an array. Your `data` variable contains a string, thus when you call `data[4]`, you get the 5th character in your string.

There's the `parseFloat` method for parsing your string into a float, if you want it like that.

Comment: Unary operator `+` will probably be faster than `parseFloat`.

Comment: Thanks for that, too much time in front of the screen and I missed something so simple

Answer (score 0):

I started with the comment, but I'll just write an answer.

You are addressing `data` and think of it as your array, while in fact that is just one value.
Check your first value: `39.9283296`.
Indices 4/5/6 are 2/8/3 accordingly.
That's what you are seeing, not the "floated" numbers rounded.

Check where you get `data` from, looks like you just need `data` itself as your value.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is like this:

```
$.each(values, function(key,data) {
 console.log(key +": "+data);
})
```

So let's take a look at the first line of output:

```
4: 39.9283296
```

Ok, what is `key` and what is `data`?

```
key: "4"
data: "39.9283296" // I assume it's string according to result you got
```

So, what does `console.log(data[4] + " " +data[5] + " " +data[6])` give you?

```
"39.9283296"[4] // 2
     ^
"39.9283296"[5] // 8
      ^
"39.9283296"[6] // 3
       ^
```

You got it, `2 8 3`.